# Ubuntu - Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I've searched the solution but so far I did not get the right one I can apply.

Host: Ubuntu 14.04

when I typed the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev:i386
```

I got the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libxtst-dev:i386 : Depends: libxext-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libxi-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And some other packages the same error.

Please let me know how to resolve these conflicts, theanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can correct the error by requesting apt to install the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 libxi-dev:i386
```

I prefer to use [`aptitude`'s](https://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/) curses-based "GUI" to navigate through the dependencies to resolve any issues.

Comment: Would you explain your preference in more detail so that I can take your approach?

Comment: Using aptitutde I can navigate through the dependencies of the packages. I can mark packages for install/upgrade/remove/purge and when the set of operations is entered I can then tell aptitude to go and do the set of operations. It makes it easy to resolve conflicts, especially when packages must be changed together due their relationships. apt-get was built as a proof-of-concept demo and isn't as user friendly. (I did use apt-get for many years, before aptitude was available and have used aptitude for over ten years since)